# How to get all the photos when user uploads 2 or more in Facebook for iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, sdk

```
{
    comments =         {
        count = 0;
    };
    "created_time" = "2013-01-23T06:12:43+0000";
    from =         {
        id = 1171029418;
        name = "Ilse Anhy";
    };
    icon = "https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/rsrc.php/v2/yz/r/StEh3RhPvjk.gif";
    id = "1171029418_10200426347839190";
    link = "https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10200426378279951&set=a.3604514069432.2168112.1171029418&type=1&relevant_count=2";
    "object_id" = 10200426378279951;
    picture = "https://fbcdn-photos-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/265145_10200426378279951_1504367216_s.jpg";
    privacy =         {
        value = "";
    };
    "status_type" = "added_photos";
    story = "Ilse Anhy added 2 new photos.";
    "story_tags" =         {
        0 =             (
                            {
                id = 1171029418;
                length = 9;
                name = "Ilse Anhy";
                offset = 0;
                type = user;
            }
        );
    };
    type = photo;
    "updated_time" = "2013-01-23T06:12:43+0000";
}
```

In the "story" object it says "Ilse Anhy added 2 new photos."
In the "picture" object it only gives a reference to a single photo. How would I be able to retrieve the other photo?